# How can I make these Buttons round? (Flutter)

Tags: flutter

I am a middle school student learning Flutter, and I am trying to make a setting toggle in my alarm app.

However, when I click the setting widget, I want the grey box and the white background to exactly overlap that is aesthetically better than what I have now. Currently, the two regions of grey box and white background do not quite match.

How can I make the two regions to exactly overlap?

[image]

```
AppBar(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  actions: [
    MenuAnchor(
      builder: (BuildContext context, settingController, child) =>
      IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _isRotated = !_isRotated;
          });

          if (settingController.isOpen) {
            settingController.close();
          } else {
            settingController.open();
          }
        },
        icon: AnimatedRotation(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
          turns: _isRotated ? 90 : 0, // 회전 각도
          curve: Curves.easeInOut,
          child: Icon(
            Icons.settings,
            size: 35,
          ),
        ),
        tooltip: 'setting',
      ),
      menuChildren: List<MenuItemButton>.generate(
        4,
        (int index) => MenuItemButton(
          onPressed: () => setState(() => selectedMenu =
              //SampleItemValue.values[index] as SampleItem?),
              SampleItemValue.values[index]),
          style: MenuItemButton.styleFrom(
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            ),
          ),
          child: const SizedBox(
            width: 200,
            height: 50,
            // child: DecoratedBox(
            //   decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
            // ),
            child: Text('hello'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user elevated button as per your needs.

```
ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text(
            'Raised Button',
          ),
          onPressed: () {},
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),  // add radius as per your needs.
          ),
         
        ),
```

Comment: I have faces this issue. This is working fine for @zeel code. Thank you for your support.